# Why my menu is not aligning?

Tags: html, css, layout, button

I'm trying to create in HTML/CSS the following menu inside of a sidebar:

[myimage http://img1.firenex.net/9Z0eupHnvV7LIPQd950r.png](http://img1.firenex.net/9Z0eupHnvV7LIPQd950r.png)

Every button has its own corresponding pressed/non-pressed image, and when hovered its opacity moves from 0.8 to 1.0 via CSS.

The problem is that I get is this:

[myimage2 http://img1.firenex.net/nooUcfe0HvvfMaCmz6N8.png](http://img1.firenex.net/nooUcfe0HvvfMaCmz6N8.png)

Not quite the result I expected :)

This is my HTML:

```
    <div id="homepageBtn"></div>
    <div id="progressiBtn"></div>
    <div id="interessiBtn"></div>
    <div id="friendzoneBtn"></div>
    <div id="emailBtn"></div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#homepageBtn {
    background:url(img/buttons/homepage_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 88px;
    height: 79px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: left;
}

#homepageBtn:hover {
    background:url(img/buttons/homepage_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#homepageBtn:active {
    background:url(img/buttons/homepage_btn_pressed.png) bottom right no-repeat;
}

#progressiBtn {
    background:url(img/buttons/progressi_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 88px;
    height: 79px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#progressiBtn:hover {
    background:url(img/buttons/progressi_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#progressiBtn:active {
    background:url(img/buttons/progressi_btn_pressed.png) bottom right no-repeat;
}

#interessiBtn {
    background:url(img/buttons/interessi_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 88px;
    height: 79px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}

#interessiBtn:hover {
    background:url(img/buttons/interessi_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#interessiBtn:active {
    background:url(img/buttons/interessi_btn_pressed.png) bottom right no-repeat;
}

#friendzoneBtn {
    background:url(img/buttons/friendzone_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 88px;
    height: 79px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#friendzoneBtn:hover {
    background:url(img/buttons/friendzone_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#friendzoneBtn:active {
    background:url(img/buttons/friendzone_btn_pressed.png) bottom right no-repeat;
}

#emailBtn {
    background:url(img/buttons/email_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 188px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    clear: left;
}

#emailBtn:hover {
    background:url(img/buttons/email_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#emailBtn:active {
    background:url(img/buttons/email_btn_pressed.png) bottom right no-repeat;
}
```

I really don't know if I am using the correct method to do this, I would appreciate any solutions at this point... thanks in advance.

PS: this happens with Chrome, with IE for example I get it showed correctly

Comment: Friendly advice: Wrap the code up in a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) and post the link here. It might get answered quicklier. :)

Comment: The code you posted is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/a2Hc5/ 
Maybe the problem is in other code area...
By the way it would be better to rethink the html in a "container way", not with just floating adjacent divs.

Comment: What do you mean for container way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using clear property incorrectly. you can use this code.

```
<div id="homepageBtn"></div>
<div id="progressiBtn"></div>
<div style="clear:both;border:0px"></div>
<div id="interessiBtn"></div>
<div id="friendzoneBtn"></div>
<div style="clear:both;border:0px"></div>
<div id="emailBtn"></div>​
```

And Remove Clear:left from following CSS

```
#interessiBtn {
    background:url(img/buttons/interessi_btn.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 88px;
    height: 79px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    clear: left;            <-- Remove this
    float: left;
}
```

[Demo Code](http://jsfiddle.net/eUG8c/)

Answer (score 0):

margin-top:.. or padding top but  even a better solution is that do the following amendment ,

Add a new   and  do it like this

```
  <div id="upper">//further divide it in two parts 
  <div id="homepageBtn"></div>//here goes homepage button 
  <div id="progressiBtn"></div>
  </div >  //end of  upper
```

and do  same thing  for  bottom Div

```
  <div id="bottom">//further divide it in two parts 
  <div id="friendzoneBtn"></div>
  <div id="emailBtn"></div>
  </div >  // end of bottom
```

and  not whatever  the dimensions  you set for `upper`  div or  then bottom div    your content will be easily adjustable there

Comment: then there is not the problem i  did run its fine .  you should have messed the divs  in wrong way nothing else